# How to know how many class elements have been selected on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on wishlist, i have heart icon on each item, Now i want to display total number of item added in wishlist. What is proper way to do this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.fav-icon', function() {
    var icon = $(this);
    var icon_fa_icon = icon.attr('data-prefix');

    if (icon_fa_icon === "far") {
      icon.attr('data-prefix', 'fas');

      $('.search-list-box .fav-icon').each(function() {
        var fasLength = $(this).attr('data-prefix', 'fas');
        var wishlistDiv = +$(fasLength).length;
        $('.wishlist_count sup').text(wishlistDiv);
      });
    } else {
      icon.attr('data-prefix', 'far');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <span class="wishlist_count">
    <i class="far text-orange fa-heart"></i>
    <sup>0</sup>
  </span>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Part of your problem is with these lines:

```
var fasLength = $(this).attr('data-prefix', 'fas');
var wishlistDiv = +$(fasLength).length;
```

That first line is setting the `data-prefix` attribute to `fas` on all elements so they are all chosen on first click. As it's selecting all elements the count is wrong. To fix this you need to use an attribute selector:

```
var fasLength = $('[data-prefix="fas"]').length;
```

Finally you also need to amend the count of selected items when something is deselected, so the count logic should be run outside of the `if` condition. The calculation also does not need the `each()`loop.

The complete logic will then look like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('click', '.fav-icon', function() {
    var $icon = $(this).attr('data-prefix', function(i, v) {
      return v == 'far' ? 'fas' : 'far';
    });

    var fasLength = $('[data-prefix="fas"]').length;
    $('.wishlist_count sup').text(fasLength);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-EIHISlAOj4zgYieurP0SdoiBYfGJKkgWedPHH4jCzpCXLmzVsw1ouK59MuUtP4a1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  <span class="wishlist_count">
    <i class="far text-orange fa-heart"></i>
    <sup>0</sup>
  </span>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
<div class="search-list-box">
  <i class="fav-icon far fa-heart text-orange"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks its working fine but on unselecting icon its not working

Comment: I edited , @Rory plz review and approve, it will work for both on select and unselect.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan this is not working on safari browser in iphone.